# Function 'not declared in this scope', but it is! Isn't it?

Tags: c++

> 'initPhysics' was not declared in this scope.

I have simplified my program as much as I could; here it is:

helloworld.hpp

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_HPP
#define HELLOWORLD_HPP

class testWorld {
    public:
        testWorld() {}
        ~testWorld() {}
        void initPhysics();
};
#endif
```

hello.cpp

```
#include "helloworld.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void testWorld::initPhysics() {
    cout << "Initiating physics..." << endl;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    testWorld* world;
    world = new testWorld();
    world<-initPhysics();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with the command

```
g++ -c hello.cpp
```

and get the error

```
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hello.cpp:14:21: error: ‘initPhysics’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why doesn't the compiler see the declaration of initPhysics, even though I included helloworld.hpp?

Comment: Ok, what is `<-` supposed to do? You probably mean `->`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be world->initPhysics() instead of world<-initPhysics(), or am I confused?

Comment: [I don't understand the problem, works perfectly fine for me. :)](http://ideone.com/r71Dj)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be `world->initPhysics()`, not `world<-initPhysics()`

Your version is being read as the expression "world is less than -1 multiplied by the result of the global function initPhysics()" and it's that global function that it can't find.

And although this is obviously test code, I'd just like to point out that if you allocate an object with `new`, you must explicitly `delete` it somewhere.

Comment: And that if the variable is just used in a single scope, you probably don't want to allocate it dynamically at all.

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else who answered! You are all, of course, completely right. I changed '<-' to '->' and now it works just as it's supposed to. And I'll try to remember to delete things, I'm just not used to it from Java.

Answer (score 3):

`world<-initPhysics()` should be `world->initPhysics()`?

Answer (score 3):

Learn to read the `->` operator (not `<-`!) in `ptr->member` as "*member* in whatever *ptr* points to", in other words: it is a somewhat literal representation of an actual pointer. So in your case it should be

```
world->initPhysics(); // note the ->, not <-
```

---

However, while this answers your question, it's far from sufficient. There's several other problems with your code.

1. There's no need to first create an uninitialized pointer, and then initialize it. That's error-prone, and you should instead initialize it immediately:

   ```
   testWorld* world = new testWorld();
   world->initPhysics();
   ```
2. Note that in C++ every object created using the `new` operator needs to be destroyed explicitly using the `delete` operator:

   ```
   delete  world; // sounds scary, BTW
   ```
3. You seem to be coming from a language like Java or C#, where everything must be `new`'d. In C++ this is not true. By default you should create objects on the stack, rather than on the heap:

   ```
   testWorld world;
   world.initPhysics();
   ```
4. But there's still a problem with your code. What you have now is what's known as two-phase construction. As a user of your class I need to remember to call an initialization function before I use an instance of it. But that's what constructors are for! A constructor should fully initialize an object, so that it is in a usable state. You should call your initialization function from the constructor instead:

   ```
   testWorld() {initPhysics();}
   ```

Physics is an integral part of the world, and shouldn't be added as an afterthought. `:)`

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I'm used to Java, so I still have a lot to learn when it comes to pointers and initialising and deleting things. There is (probably) a reason for initPhysics not being in the constructor though. Not sure what yet, but I'm trying to understand someone else's code by reconstructing it from scratch, so hopefully I'll learn it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You want `world->initPhysics();` instead of `world<-initPhysics();`

Answer (score 0):

```
world<-initPhysics();
```

Here, your arrow is in the wrong direction. You should have :

```
world->initPhysics();
```

Answer (score 0):

`world<-initPhysics();` should be `world->initPhysics();`